# Running story failed after upgrading to latest jbehave version 4.5.1

Tags: jbehave

I have been using older jbehave version - 3.9.5, tried to upgrade to latest version - 4.5.1. However, while executing tests, it fails with AbstractMethodError

Below is the exact error encountered:

```
Failed to run story ABC/ABC-144.31.story
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.jbehaveforjira.javaclient.JiraStoryReporter.beforeScenario(Lorg/jbehave/core/model/Scenario;)V
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter.beforeScenario(DelegatingStoryReporter.java:58)
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConcurrentStoryReporter.beforeScenario(ConcurrentStoryReporter.java:176)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:1007)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.performScenarios(PerformableTree.java:907)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:882)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:435)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:402)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:293)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Based on this error and after debugging understood that before Scenario (String title) and two other methods have been deprecated in latest version.

I commented these methods in below classes/interface locally and rebuilt my application, but it didn't solve the problem. Please help to provide any help/suggestion.

```
org.jbehave.core.reporters.ConcurrentStoryReporter, org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter,
org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporter
org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree
```

Comment: `com.jbehaveforjira.javaclient.JiraStoryReporter` should be updated to the latest version, are you owner of this class?

Comment: It seems it's a part of external library: check if you use the latest version, if yes, then you can report a new issue: https://bitbucket.org/pristrom/jbehave-for-jira-java-client/issues

Comment: Thank you for the link, i couldn't find new version of this class. However, I implemented new methods in my local copy of JiraStoryReporter, but still failed with same error but for another class(this already updated as mentioned above): java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 at org.jbehave.core.reporters.DelegatingStoryReporter.beforeScenario(DelegatingStoryReporter.java:58)

Comment: please update your question with new details

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update my jbehave from 4.1.3 to 4.5.1. I encountered the same error when only updating jbehave-core. So in addition to updating your jbehave version, you must also update other dependencies in your project. In my case, I updated the following: jbehave-core(to 4.5.1), serenity-core(to 1.9.40), serenity-jbehave(to 1.46.0). Please check your pom.xml or the jar files in your build path.